# There exists an integer $n$ such that $n$ and $n+2$ are quadratic residue modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We have $p>5$ is a prime number. I want to prove that: There exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that both equations $x^2\equiv n\pmod p$ and $y^2\equiv a+2\pmod p$ have integer solutions.

I could prove if $p\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$ then we chose $n=0$ (since $-2$ will be quadratic residue modulo $p$). But I have no ideas for the other cases: $p\equiv 5,7\pmod 8$.Help me!

Comment: Please fix the statement, I believe $a$ should be $n$.

Comment: This is also true for $p=5$ since both $-1$ and $1$ are quadratic residues mod 5. It is also true for $p=3$. For $p=2$ it is trivial. So $p>5$ is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using the pigeonhole principle. Since $p$ is odd, write $p=2k+1$. It is well known that there are $k+1$ squares and $k$ non-squares modulo $p$. Denote by $X$ the set of squares modulo $p$: this set has $k+1$ elements. Consider the map $f: \Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ which is defined by
$$f(x)=x+2 \ \pmod{p}$$
Clearly this map is injective. This implies that $f(X)$ has $k+1$ elements.
Since
$$(k+1)+(k+1)=p+1 >p$$
the two sets $X$ and $f(X)$ are not disjoint. Hence there exists some $x \in X$ such that $x+2 \in X$.

This is exactly what you wanted to prove.

REMARK: this proof works for any injective map $f$. For example we can similarly prove that there exist a square $x$ such that $x+24$ is a square.